# How to prevent to anonymous access to Mongo DB?

Tags: mongodb, security, authentication, nosql

I still don`t can prevent to anonymous access to Mongo DB after do below steps.

1- Create admin user with this command

```
mongod --port 27017 --logpath D:\Files\Sessions\log\mongo.log --dbpath D:\Files\Sessions\data\db
```

2- Create mongod.conf file with this config

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "D:/Files/Sessions/log/mongo.log"
storage:
   dbPath: "D:/Files/Sessions/data/db"
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1, localhost
   port: 27017
```

3- Execute `mongod --config "D:\Files\Sessions\mongod.conf"`

4- Create admin user with

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "myUserAdmin",
    pwd: passwordPrompt(), // or cleartext password
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
  }
)
```

5- Update mongod.conf with add this config to that

```
security:
   authorization: enabled
```

6- Execute `mongod --config "D:\Files\Sessions\mongod.conf"`

I also in between steps, many times execute this command

```
mongod --port 27017 --logpath D:\Files\Sessions\log\mongo.log --dbpath D:\Files\Sessions\data\db --auth
```

In final, I can create new admin user and authenticate with that but still i can also authenticate as anonymous user without credential!

Just in case =>
mongo version: 4.2, windows 10

What`s wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can also authenticate as anonymous user without credential". Note, even with authentication you can connect to Mongo Database without any credentials but you are not permitted to execute any command (apart from stuff like `db.getMongo()`, `db.help()`, `db.version()`, etc.)

Comment: Did you shutdown the database before you restarted it?

Comment: When you run mongod it tells you the configuration it's using. Verify auth is enabled there. There is published documentation for enabling auth, verify you followed all steps correctly.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  yes. i shutdown that but i cannot restart with command and i restart that with services app as manual. i saw a video in youtube that guy by this steps did this job but for me doesn`t work

Comment: "cannot start" is not a useful error messages, what is the error? You can check loaded configuration with command `db.serverCmdLineOpts()` Command `db.runCommand( { connectionStatus: 1 })` may also help

Comment: Maybe the `--dbpath` is different to what you specified in your `mongod.conf` file. - Then you would have two different fully independent databases.